I Need to include "Alias /index.html" to find my root html application when mixed with Flask mod_wsgi applications
Here is my 000-default-le-ssl.conf file
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
DirectoryIndex index.html
Alias /index.html /var/www/html/        

WSGIDaemonProcess sampleapps processes=1 python-path=/var/www/sampleapp/env:/var/www/sampleapp/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages
    WSGIScriptAlias /blog /var/www/sampleapp/env/main.py
<Directory /var/www/sampleapp/env>
    WSGIProcessGroup sampleapps
    Require all granted
</Directory>
Alias /static /var/www/sampleapp/env/static 

When I don't include the "Alias /index.html /var/www/html" line I get a 404 error for the root web address. When I do include it, the only way I can access my HTML app is using http://{web address}/index.html ?
The Flask App at /blog works fine, but the HTML app at root does not?
I have Googled this all morning, but I can't find anything. Any assistance would be appreciated.
I tried
ServerAlias / /var/www/html
but this broke my Flask Application - but the root HTML app starts working.
Using
Alias / /var/www/html/
also breaks the Flask Application.
